# Open generated pdf in browser in another tab

Tags: php, fpdf

I'm generating pdf through FPDF. Now all I need is to open this generated pdf in browser.

Searched lot for it, but all am getting is solution for existing pdf where as here we need solution for generated pdf through fpdf.

Following is my code:

```
<?php   require('../pdf/fpdf.php');
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',12);  
$pdf->Cell(40,10,'This is demo');
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

Comment: Solved, it worked after IDM extension was disabled!

Answer (score 2):

For people still looking, adding target="_blank" to your form tag will open the PDF in a new window.

HTML:

```
<form method="GET" action="/target-destination/" id="pdfForm"  target="_blank">
 <!-- Content goes here -->
</form>
```

mPDF:

```
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
$mpdf->WriteHTML('Hello World');

$mpdf->Output('filename.pdf', 'I');
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick browse of the [FPDF documentation](http://www.fpdf.org/) shows that you can add a couple of parameters to the `Output()` function call to provide display in browser or download functionality

```
string Output([string dest [, string name [, boolean isUTF8]]])
```

See more [here](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/output.htm).

For example:

```
<?php   require('../pdf/fpdf.php');
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',12);  
$pdf->Cell(40,10,'This is demo');
$pdf->Output('I');
?>
```

The above example uses 'I' for inline. The other options are:

```
I: send the file inline to the browser. The PDF viewer is used if available.
D: send to the browser and force a file download with the name given by name.
F: save to a local file with the name given by name (may include a path).
S: return the document as a string.
```

It is all available in the [documentation](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/output.htm).

Comment: it would be helpful if you could show how to implement that in code above

Comment: Did not show how it works, and in my case, doing what you said caused the plugin to crash.

Answer (score 0):

The FPDF inline method demonstration will attempt to insecurely open an About:Blank which should not be relied on as a method for Inline Display, it simply triggers a security response in the browser to auto download to AV check in sandbox. Use one of the traditional methods like A Href=download I will trust that more and can run a URL checker on your link first...

[image]